# at any time map view contains only one location marker.Can anyone help me to do so?

Tags: android

I am doing a project in which, when the user clicks at a particular location, a location marker should come there.If the user clicks at another location the location marker should go and marker should appear at new location, ie..at any time map view contains only one location marker.Can anyone help me to do so programatically???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When user click on the map get the latitude and longitude there and remove the  old overlay and call the method to create new overlay with this new point

see this to get latitude and longitude on touch

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code you will have to extends `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` in your Activity

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.Image, null);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,mapOverlays.get(index).getPoint(), 0, -70, LayoutParams.MODE_MAP | LayoutParams.CENTER);

    }
```

And an image will be Shown at the place where you have tapped.